# How to use a User Control XAML within a Class Library

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a sub project wich is a class and contains DataLib.cs and an user controll MediumTile.xaml. This user control will be the generated to an image to use it as tile background. But before I have to change a few thing dynamicly. So how can I get controll above the LayoutRoot inside MediumTile.xaml for example to set the background color?

Something like this:

```
MediumTile.LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 206, 23, 23);
```

Comment: Just give it a name. eg: <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

Comment: of course it has this name already

Comment: Ah, this is in a separate project. You can expose a control by creating a property: public Grid Layout { get { return LayoutRoot; }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MediumTile.xaml` probably exists in some kind of namespace.

You can find the namespace of the UserControl in the top of the file beside the x:Class declaration.

Typically it'll look something like

```
x:Class="MyProject.UserControls.MediumTile"
```

if your project is set up normally.

If you look at the `MediumTile.xaml.cs`, you should see a namespace like so

```
namespace MyProject.UserControls
{
    public partial class MediumTile : UserControl
    ...
```

---

First off, you will need to reference your subproject.

Assuming you have a project structure like so...

```
CurrentProject/
    -MyPage.xaml

SubProject/
    -MediumTile.xaml
```

Right-click your Solution in Visual Studio and click `Properties`.

Under Properties select `Project Dependencies`.

Choose the CurrentProject in the dropdown.

In the `Depends On` checkbox field, choose the SubProject.

Click on `StartUp Project` in the side bar.

Make sure `Single StartUp Project` points to CurrentProject. If not, set it.

Now you're done setting up, you'll need to actually use `MediumTile.xaml` now.

---

1. To use the MediumTile UserControl in another XAML file, you will need to declare

   xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:MyProject.UserControls"

inside the page header, and call

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <customControls:MediumTile/>
...
```

1. To use this UserControl in another CS file, you will need to import the namespace

   using MyProject.UserControls;

at the top of the page, and reference your control like so (depending on your usercontrol's constructor),

```
MediumTile mediumTile = new MediumTile()
```

---

About your `LayoutRoot` problem, you can simply set the Background color directly on the UserControl. UserControl inherits from Control, which has the Background property already.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it for `windows phone 8`, but for normal desktop applications, you can do it by adding the following references:

- PresentationCore
- PresentationFramework
- WindowsBase

Then you can create and access a `Control` in a normal way.

Comment: can you give an example of the syntax please